# filter list object with list list tring (dynamic)

Tags: typescript

I did search on Stack Overflow, but I am still confused.I did search on Stack Overflow, but I am still confused.
I did search on Stack Overflow, but I am still confused.

```
//There are two JavaScript arrays: a and array: b
var a = [
{
inputList:['S','600 gram']
},
{
inputList:['X','800 gram']
}
];
var b = [
{Size: 'S', productVariantId: '8cb8eaed-7310-41a5-a717-8ccc6694c52c', Weight: '600 gram'},
{Size: 'S', productVariantId: 'a2c3b56f-075f-4c65-8f5c-a0cd188a735b', Weight: '800 gram'},
{Size: 'X', productVariantId: '8cb8eaed-7310-41a5-a717-8ccc6694c52c', Weight: '600 gram'},
{Size: 'X', productVariantId: 'a2c3b56f-075f-4c65-8f5c-a0cd188a735b', Weight: '800 gram'}
];

expect c=[
{Size: 'S', productVariantId: '8cb8eaed-7310-41a5-a717-8ccc6694c52c', Weight: '600 gram'},
{Size: 'X', productVariantId: 'a2c3b56f-075f-4c65-8f5c-a0cd188a735b', Weight: '800 gram'}
]

a & b is dynamic it can changes 
ex: b=[
{Color: 'S', productVariantId: '8cb8eaed-7310-41a5-a717-8ccc6694c52c', Styles: '600 gram'}
]
filter array 2 from condition is array 1

I want to expect c=[
{Size: 'S', productVariantId: '8cb8eaed-7310-41a5-a717-8ccc6694c52c', Weight: '600 gram'},
{Size: 'X', productVariantId: 'a2c3b56f-075f-4c65-8f5c-a0cd188a735b', Weight: '800 gram'}
]
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Is not understandable what you are asking and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Direct way

```
const filtered = b.filter(
  (element) => {
    return  (element.Size === a[0].inputList[0] &&  element.Weight === a[0].inputList[1]) ||  (element.Size === a[1].inputList[0] &&  element.Weight === a[1].inputList[1]) 
  }
)
```

---

Typing better for B (your data source)

```
type B = {productVariantId:string; [key :string]: string}
const b : Array<B> = [
{Size: 'S', productVariantId: '8cb8eaed-7310-41a5-a717-8ccc6694c52c', Weight: '600 gram'},
{Size: 'S', productVariantId: 'a2c3b56f-075f-4c65-8f5c-a0cd188a735b', Weight: '800 gram'},
{Size: 'X', productVariantId: '8cb8eaed-7310-41a5-a717-8ccc6694c52c', Weight: '600 gram'},
{Size: 'X', productVariantId: 'a2c3b56f-075f-4c65-8f5c-a0cd188a735b', Weight: '800 gram'}
];

const myfilter2 = (source : Array<B>, filters : typeof a) => {
  return source.filter(
      (element) => {
          for(const filterParams of a) {
            const keep = element.Size === filterParams.inputList[0] &&  element.Weight === filterParams.inputList[1];
            if(keep) return true;
          }
       return false;
    }
  )
}
```

this assume that filter are always on **size** and **weight**.

---

If filters should be dynamic too
you should go ahead with typing a :

```
    type A = { inputList: Array<{ [key: string]: string }> };
const a2: Array<A> = [
    {
        inputList: [{ Size: 'S', Weight: '600 gram' }]
    },
    {
        inputList: [{ Size: 'X', Weight: '800 gram' }]
    }
];

const myfilter3 = (source : Array<B>, filters : Array<A>) => {
  return source.filter(
      (element) => {
          for(const filterParams of filters) {
            let keep = true;
            for(const filter of filterParams.inputList){
              for(const key of Object.keys(filter)){
                keep = keep && element[key] === filter[key] ;
              }
              if(keep) return true
              }
          }
       return false;
    }
  )
}
```